# Bricks disappearing yet ball bouncing off from them in html5 brick breaker game

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I was following the tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript to create the basic js games in HTML.
I followed this tutorial and created the game with js as shown:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth)/2;
    var paddleY = (canvas.height - paddleHeight);
    var paddleColour = "#0095DD";
    var drawPaddle = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(paddleX, paddleY, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = (paddleColour);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;
    var movepaddle = function () {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler, false);

        function keyDownHandler(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            rightPressed = true;
          }
          else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressed = true;
          }
        }
        function keyUpHandler(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            rightPressed = false;
          }
          else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressed = false;
          }
        }
        if ( rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth ) {
            paddleX += 7;
        }
        else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0 ) {
            paddleX -= 7;
        }
    }

    var ballRadius = 10;
    var ballColour = "#0095DD";
    var ballX = canvas.width/2;
    var ballY = canvas.height-ballRadius-paddleHeight;
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;
    var drawBall = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = ballColour;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    var moveBall = function () {
        ballX = ballX + dx;
        ballY = ballY + dy;
    }

    var bricksRowCount = 5;
    var bricksColumnCount = 8;
    var bricksOffsetLeft = 30;
    var brickWidth = 100;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickHeight = 24;
    var bricksArray = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < bricksColumnCount ; i++ ) {
        bricksArray[i] = [];
        for( let j = 0; j < bricksRowCount; j++ ) {
            bricksArray[i][j] = {x: 0, y: 0, status: 1};
        }
    }
    var drawBricks = function () {
        for ( let i = 0; i < bricksColumnCount ; i++ ) {
            for( let j = 0; j < bricksRowCount; j++ ) {
                if(bricksArray[i][j].status == 1) {
                    let b = bricksArray[i][j];
                    b.x = bricksOffsetLeft * (i+1) + brickWidth * i;
                    b.y = brickOffsetTop * (j+1) + brickHeight * j;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(b.x, b.y, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }

    }


    var collisionDetection = function () {
        if ( ballX + ballRadius > canvas.width || ballX < 0 )
            dx = -dx;
        else if ( ballY + ballRadius > canvas.height || ballY < 0) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        else if ( ballX > paddleX && ballX < paddleX + paddleWidth && ballY > canvas.height - ballRadius - paddleHeight ) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        for(let c = 0; c < bricksColumnCount; c++ ) {
            for(let r = 0; r < bricksRowCount; r++ ) {
                if ( ballX > bricksArray[c][r].x && ballX < bricksArray[c][r].x + brickWidth && ballY > bricksArray[c][r].y && ballY < bricksArray[c][r].y + brickHeight ) {
                    dy = -dy;
                    bricksArray[c][r].status = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var draw = function () {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawPaddle();
        moveBall();
        movepaddle();
        drawBricks();
        collisionDetection();
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    draw();
```

The problem is that the ball is bouncing off the invisible blocks in my case, while the ball doesnt bounce off the invisible bricks. Moreover, there are times when the ball follows a horizontal trajectory.
Can anyone help me where this problem is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

When you make the collision detection you have to add as a condition that brick status is not 0 or is greater than 0. Otherwise the brick, although invisible is participating in the collision detection and the ball still bounces off that brick. I hope this helps.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth)/2;
    var paddleY = (canvas.height - paddleHeight);
    var paddleColour = "#0095DD";
    var drawPaddle = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(paddleX, paddleY, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = (paddleColour);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;
    var movepaddle = function () {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler, false);

        function keyDownHandler(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            rightPressed = true;
          }
          else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressed = true;
          }
        }
        function keyUpHandler(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            rightPressed = false;
          }
          else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressed = false;
          }
        }
        if ( rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth ) {
            paddleX += 7;
        }
        else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0 ) {
            paddleX -= 7;
        }
    }

    var ballRadius = 10;
    var ballColour = "#0095DD";
    var ballX = canvas.width/2;
    var ballY = canvas.height-ballRadius-paddleHeight;
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;
    var drawBall = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = ballColour;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    var moveBall = function () {
        ballX = ballX + dx;
        ballY = ballY + dy;
    }

    var bricksRowCount = 5;
    var bricksColumnCount = 8;
    var bricksOffsetLeft = 30;
    var brickWidth = 100;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickHeight = 24;
    var bricksArray = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < bricksColumnCount ; i++ ) {
        bricksArray[i] = [];
        for( let j = 0; j < bricksRowCount; j++ ) {
            bricksArray[i][j] = {x: 0, y: 0, status: 1};
        }
    }
    var drawBricks = function () {
        for ( let i = 0; i < bricksColumnCount ; i++ ) {
            for( let j = 0; j < bricksRowCount; j++ ) {
                if(bricksArray[i][j].status == 1) {
                    let b = bricksArray[i][j];
                    b.x = bricksOffsetLeft * (i+1) + brickWidth * i;
                    b.y = brickOffsetTop * (j+1) + brickHeight * j;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(b.x, b.y, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }

    }


    var collisionDetection = function () {
        if ( ballX + ballRadius > canvas.width || ballX < 0 )
            dx = -dx;
        else if ( ballY + ballRadius > canvas.height || ballY < 0) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
      
      
        else if ( ballX > paddleX && ballX < paddleX + paddleWidth && ballY > canvas.height - ballRadius - paddleHeight ) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
      
      
        for(let c = 0; c < bricksColumnCount; c++ ) {
            for(let r = 0; r < bricksRowCount; r++ ) {
              //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              if(bricksArray[c][r].status > 0){
              ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if ( ballX > bricksArray[c][r].x && ballX < bricksArray[c][r].x + brickWidth && ballY > bricksArray[c][r].y && ballY < bricksArray[c][r].y + brickHeight ) {
                    dy = -dy;
                    bricksArray[c][r].status = 0;
                   
                }
                
              }
            }
          
   
        }
        
      
    }

    var draw = function () {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawPaddle();
        moveBall();
        movepaddle();
        drawBricks();
        collisionDetection();
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thgis didnt work, as I had already added that line. You can check it here: https://codepen.io/prasoonmayank/pen/GXeVvX

Comment: No you didn't ad that line. You have to add this condition: `if(bricksArray[c][r].status > 0){ . . . ` when you check for collision detection. You paint the brick only if status > 0. Please check  your forks on codepen.

Comment: @Mayank Your code does not have that condition in your collisionDetection